# System.setErr() interferes with Logger

Tags: java, java.util.logging

In a larger program, I am using a static `java.util.logging.Logger` instance, but redirecting `System.err` to several different files in succession. The `Logger` fails to log the second time I try to redirect `System.err`.

Here's a test program to show the problem:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class TestRedirect {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            TestRedirect ti = new TestRedirect();
            ti.test(i);
        }
    }

    void test(int i) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream filePrintStream = new PrintStream("test" + i + ".log");
        PrintStream stderr = System.err; // Save stderr stream.
        System.setErr(filePrintStream);  // Redirect stderr to file.
        System.err.println("about to log " + i);
        logger.info("at step " + i);
        System.setErr(stderr);           // Restore stderr stream.
        filePrintStream.close();
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

**test1.log:**

```
about to log 1
Jan 28, 2014 4:34:20 PM TestRedirect test
INFO: at step 1
```

**test2.log:**

```
about to log 2
```

I thought I would see a `Logger`-generated message in **test2.log** as well. Why does the `Logger` stop working, and what could I do about this?

Comment: I usually recommend against redirecting standard streams in Java if there's another possible approach. Are you *sure* you need to use `setErr()`?

Comment: @Darkhogg: The original program was actually using a Groovy `SystemOutputInterceptor` (basically a "tee" based on a `FilteredOutputStream`) to direct stdout and stderr to a log file as well as to the console. The `SystemOutputInterceptor` calls `setErr()` under the covers. Some of the various pieces of the program were using a Logger, and some were just writing info and errors to stderr and stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the JRE is configured to load a ConsoleHandler on the root logger. Your log message will travel up to the root logger handlers by default.  The root logger handlers are loaded on demand.  In your current program, the lazy loading of the root logger ConsoleHandler is capturing your 1st redirected System.err.  After that, the root logger handler is never reloaded which is why you'll never see the log message in log 2.  Plus the 1st redirected stream is closed so now the root ConsoleHandler is writing to a closed stream.

To prove this point, add the following as the first lines of your test case main method and run the program.

```
Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers(); //Force load root logger handlers.
Logger.getLogger("").removeHandler((Handler) null);
```

You'll see that now no logger messages are recorded.  If you are curious why this works you can read the `java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger` source code for details.

What you need to do is create a [StreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html) with your redirected System.err stream and then [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler%28java.util.logging.Handler%29) and [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#removeHandler%28java.util.logging.Handler%29) the StreamHandler from your logger.  You can also toggle the use of [parent handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers%28boolean%29) on your logger config to avoid writing to the original System.err.

<s>Another possible solution would be to find all ConsoleHandler instances. Remove and close all of them. Perform the remap System.err. Then create and attach new ConsoleHandlers.</s>

JDK wise, the ConsoleHandler and ErrorManager should have been designed to use the [java.io.FileDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) which is never redirected.