# Stdout redirection with Logger

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to redirect my output to a text area (that's going to be embedded somewhere in a JFrame using the following piece of code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).info("Test");

    final JTextArea x = new JTextArea();

    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            x.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
               x.setCaretPosition(x.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    });

    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);

    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).info("Test again");
    System.out.println("Another test");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.getText());
}
```

However, when the last line executed, the JOptionPane text was only "Another test".
When I remove the first Logger line

```
Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).info("Test");
```

Then everything is redirected to the JTextArea. I suspect that after I log "Test" in the first line, the class Logger binds to the console output and won't give up even if the stdout is redirected to TextArea.

Comment: What probably happens is that the getLogger saves the `PrintStream` that is associated with `System.out`, and keeps the reference to it. Hence your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your main method [captures the current System.err stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417616/system-seterr-interferes-with-logger/).  If you remap the streams before creating the root logger handlers it will work.  You could also change the code to create a new [ConsoleHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) and add it to the root logger after you have remapped the error stream.  Look out for violating the [EDT rules of Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) with your current implementation.