# Monitoring all output to the console

Tags: java, logging, io, console

I am developing a plugin for a program, specifically Bukkit, the minecraft server, and I need to capture everything that is displayed in the console. However, for some reason, I am unable do this. The following code is what I use to apply my filters:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.gmail.neonblue858.remoteconsole.plugin;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

/**
 *
 * 
 *@author Meguy26
 *
 */
public class FilterApplyer extends BukkitRunnable {
private ClientManager man;

public FilterApplyer(ClientManager man){
    this.man = man;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    //Create handler
    LogHandler handler = new LogHandler(man);
    //Set handler to capture everything
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    //Add handler to root logger so it applies to all loggers
    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);

    //Set the system out to a filtering output stream
    System.setOut(new FilterOutputStream(System.out, man));

    //Set the system err to a filtering output stream
    System.setErr(new FilterOutputStream(System.err, man));

    }

}
```

I was under the assumption that applying a filter to the root logger as well as both system streams would allow me to catch everything. Yet there are some messages that escape the filter. I don't know why this doesn't work. Is there any way, other than loggers or System.out, that things can be printed to the console?

Note:
ClientManager, LogHandler, and FilterOutputStream in the above code are classes I wrote, and I have ensured they work properly. I am certain the problem is that I am not applying a filter to every source of printing.

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the assumption that applying a filter to the root logger as well as both system streams would allow me to catch everything.

From the [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html):

> By default a Logger will log any output messages to its [parent's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getParent--) [handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getHandlers--), and so on recursively up the tree.

When log records travel up the tree they are **not** passed to [logger.log(LogRecord)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.LogRecord-).  If you want to capture everything then you need to install handler on the root logger and ensure that all loggers have useParentHanders set to true.

You also need to be aware that the [root logger handlers are created on demand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417616/system-seterr-interferes-with-logger)